# Check all the checkboxes of a particular column of all rows in gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I created a gridview with 1 hidden boundfield, 1 Boundfield and dynamically created templated field containing checkboxes in HeaderTemplate as well as in ItemTemplate.  The No. of Checkbox columns varies according to the query.

The ID of the checkbox is generated through naming container like
Hearder Checkbox ID is "gvEmpSalaryStructure_respective-columnname"
Item Checkbox ID's is "gvEmpSalaryStructure_respective-columnname_incrementing-index(starts with 0)"

Now by selecting header checkbox of a column all the checkboxes of that column should be Checked/uncheck.

How to achieve this through javascript or any better way.
[Note: I have nil knowledge in javascript]

The link contains the image of the gridview please view it for reference.
[Dynamically Created gridview with checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwR8j.png)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the HTML-output of your GridView. From that we can offer a JavaScript/jQuery - suggestion

Comment: School Assignment? Not welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work. Assuming the ID of the CheckBox looks like this `gvEmpSalaryStructure_columnName_2`, where `2` is the column index.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#<%= GridView1.ClientID %> th input:checkbox").change(function () {
        var columnIndex = this.id.split("_")[2];
        changeAllCheckBoxes(this.checked, columnIndex);
    });

    function changeAllCheckBoxes(is_checked, columnIndex) {
        $("#<%= GridView1.ClientID %> tr").each(function () {
            $(this).find("td input:checkbox").each(function (index, element) {
                if (index == columnIndex) {
                    this.checked = is_checked;
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Its giving jscript object expected error. Do we need to add any event to the gridview for this code.

Comment: No, the `change` event is attached to `GridView1`. Check the value of `columnIndex` and see if it is an integer. You may need to change `this.id.split("_")[2];` according to the namingcontainer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".colmnHeader").on('click',function(){
    var getTDPosition= this.cellIndex;

    $("#table tr").each(function(){ 
        // get checkbox for specific colmn and make it checked
    });
});
```